Laravel migration problem with env file maybe
I just started working with Laravel and php and my supervisor just asked me to clone the Laravel repo from git and run it in my computer. the localhost/login page works, but I tried running php artisan migrate, but this occurs.
root@48cc4e852d29:/var/www/html# php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_
schema.tables where table_schema = church and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

this is what my .env file looks like
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Hb5jKxtoJ5Pixeznb9FaaFMwr9/zp+IypWXUg3D8k30=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

and i attached a photo of my database which has the url http://localhost:8081
tried to modify the env file, changed the
DB_PORT=3306 to 8081
DB_DATABASE=laravel to church

but it didn`t do nothing.
what i have to do to solve this?

change the DB_HOST=localhost to 127.0.0.1 and make sure that your DB_DATABASE and others field are correct.

same problem...

Run these command php artisan cache:clear & php artisan config:clear and then try again.
